# Algorithm to detect how many times a sequence alternates

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am a new computer science & mathematics student.I am stuck at finding an algorithm to detect how many times the sequence of numbers alternates.For e.g {3,5,6} has one alteration since 3 increases to 5 and the sequence remains increasing.Also , {3,5,6,4} has 2 alterations since it increases 3,5,6 then decreases from 6 to 4.Can someone help in finding an efficient way to detect the no. of alterations.

pc **input**: 3 5 6 2 
pc **output** : 2 (alterations)

Comment: This is really not a maths. question. How do you characterize 'efficient'?

Comment: It requires mathematical thinking to solve it , I mean a working algorithm

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? You just need to keep a running count of the number of alternations seen so far and the last number seen.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious algorithm is $O(n)$ and the problem requires at least $O(n)$ work since every element has to be examined.